# Out of memory onCreateView android fragment communication

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, oncreate

trying to learn som android here and need to work out fragment to fragment communication. It goes bananas on me, and crashes because of what seems to be a recursive call. And it seems to happen in FragmentA.onCreateView. Please help.. I got no clue!

Error:

```
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication.FragmentA.onCreateView(FragmentA.java:23)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1045)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1147)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2116)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-05 00:13:59.139    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/art﹕ [ 03-05 00:13:59.183  2238: 2238 D/AndroidRuntime ]
    Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
03-05 00:13:59.183    2238-2238/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication, PID: 2238
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available
03-05 00:13:59.421    2238-2250/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 67MB to 64MB
03-05 00:13:59.421    2238-2250/no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9773(360KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(12KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 63MB/64MB, paused 559us total 201.614ms
```

Here is my code:

```
package no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by nr1 on 04/03/15.
 */
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnClick;
    int counter = 0;
    Communicator comm;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        Log.d("FragmentA: ","onCreateView" );
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("FragmentA: ","onActivityCreated" );
        //det finnes ikke metode for å finne byId i fragment, må man bruke activity.findView...byId
        comm=(Communicator) getActivity();
        btnClick = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        Log.d("FragmentA: ","onClick" );
        counter++;
        comm.respond("The button was clicked " + counter + " times");
    }
}
```

More code:

```
package no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by nr1 on 04/03/15.
 */
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    TextView txt1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        txt1=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txwText);
    }

    public void changeText(String txtVar){

        txt1.setText(txtVar);

    }
}
```

And then some:

```
package no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Communicator {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public void respond(String data){
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentB frg2 = (FragmentB) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        frg2.changeText(data);

    }

}
```

And the interface:

```
package no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication;

/**
 * Created by nr1 on 04/03/15.
 */
public interface Communicator {

    public void respond (String data);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the layouts. I am pretty sure that you are adding a fragmentA in layoutB and fragmentB in layout A

Comment: YES! thats correct! I just found it;) I added fragment a in fragment a xml-file...daimit! Thank YOU!

Comment: I will add the answer for you to accept

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure from the stacktrace that you are adding a fragmentA in layoutB and fragmentB in layout A or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Im an idiot! I added fragment_a in the fragment_a-xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#99cc00">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me"
        android:id="@+id/btn1" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_a"
        android:name="no.clausjensen.fragmentcommunication.FragmentA"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

then ofcourse it will try to create a new fragment_a, inside fragment_a...etc! NOOBME!